# python multiline regex with intricated or intexmixed results ; is it possible to match all result in a single pattern?

Tags: python, regex, multiline

exemple of text to illustrate what i want to do : i want to match all files xxx.txt found and processed :

```
texte="""
.....................................................................
...
... found:  a_dir/a_sub_dir/aaa.txt
.....................................................................
...
... found:  a_dir/a_sub_dir/bbb.txt
.....................................................................
...
... startprocess: aaa.txt
.....................................................................
...
... found:  a_dir/a_sub_dir/ccc.txt
.....................................................................
...
... startprocess: bbb.txt
.....................................................................
...
... endprocess: aaa.txt
.....................................................................
... endprocess: bbb.txt
"""
```

1. first i try to match in a single pattern like that :

   ```
    pattern=r' .*?(found:\s+.*?((?P<filename>[a-z]+\.txt)))(?:.*?)(?P<start>startprocess:\s+(?P=filename))(?:.*?)(?P<end>endprocess:\s+(?P=filename))'
    for m in  re.finditer(pattern,texte, re.DOTALL):
        print(m.groupdict())
   ```

   resultat :

   ```
    {'filename': 'aaa.txt', 'start': 'startprocess: aaa.txt', 'end': 'endprocess: aaa.txt'}
   ```

   --> file bbb.txt is missing
2. So to match bbb.txt i research first all found files and then search them in a loop :

   ```
    list=[]
    pattern_template=r'.*?(found:\s+.*?(?P<filename>@filename@))(?:.*?)(?P<start>startprocess:\s+(?P=filename))(?:.*?)(?P<end>endprocess:\s+(?P=filename))'
    for filename in re.findall(r'(?:.*?)found:\s+.*?([a-z]+\.txt)',texte):
        pattern=pattern_template.replace('@filename@', filename)
        for m in re.finditer(pattern,texte, re.DOTALL):
            list.append(m.groupdict())
    print(list)
   ```

   resultat :

   ```
    [{'filename': 'aaa.txt', 'start': 'startprocess: aaa.txt', 'end': 'endprocess: aaa.txt'}, {'filename': 'bbb.txt', 'start': 'startprocess: bbb.txt', 'end': 'endprocess: bbb.txt'}]
   ```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Don't do it with a single pattern.  That's just silly, and as regular expressions get longer, their performance gets worse and worse.  You have a simple parsing problem -- just read it line by line and pull what you need.

Comment: i am not sure to understand, do you mean it is ok with the second method: collectiong all files found and then match files processed one by one  ?

Comment: i understood what you means by "just read it line by line",  because keyword (found, startprocess, endprocess) is followed by the filename... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to do it line by line because each tag (found, startprocess, endprocess) is followed by the filename.
And so more faster than trying to match all tags in multiline mode.
(thanks to Tim Roberts)

Python script with the solution line by line :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

# input string
input_str="""
.....................................................................
...
... found:  a_dir/a_sub_dir/aaa.txt
.....................................................................
...
... found:  a_dir/a_sub_dir/bbb.txt
.....................................................................
...
... startprocess: aaa.txt
.....................................................................
...
... found:  a_dir/a_sub_dir/ccc.txt
.....................................................................
...
... startprocess: bbb.txt
.....................................................................
...
... endprocess: aaa.txt
.....................................................................
... endprocess: bbb.txt
"""

# split str into lines
Lines=input_str.split("\n")

Dic_found={}
Dic_created={}
Dic_ended={}
for line in Lines:
    for filename in re.findall(r'^.*?found:\s+.*?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.txt)', line):
        Dic_found[filename]="OUI"
        Dic_created[filename]="NON"
        Dic_ended[filename]="NON"
    for filename in re.findall(r'^.*?startprocess:\s+.*?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.txt)', line):
        Dic_created[filename]="OUI"
    for filename in re.findall(r'^.*?endprocess:\s+.*?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.txt)', line):
        Dic_ended[filename]="OUI"

# print matched data for found, startprocess, endprocess
print("found:",Dic_found)
print("startprocess:",Dic_created)
print("endprocess:",Dic_ended)
```

Resultat :

```
found: {'aaa.txt': 'OUI', 'bbb.txt': 'OUI', 'ccc.txt': 'OUI'}
startprocess: {'aaa.txt': 'OUI', 'bbb.txt': 'OUI', 'ccc.txt': 'NON'}
endprocess: {'aaa.txt': 'OUI', 'bbb.txt': 'OUI', 'ccc.txt': 'NON'}
```